# List of windows users remotely

Tags: list

I would like to know how to retrieve the list of users that are logged onto a Remote machine. I can do it with qwinsta /server:xxxx, but would like to do it in C#.

Answer (score 1):

check out wmi in .net under `system.management`.

something like:

```
ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions(); 
conn.Authority = "ntdlmdomain:NAMEOFDOMAIN"; 
conn.Username = ""; 
conn.Password = ""; 

ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\remotecomputer\root\cimv2", conn); 
ms.Connect(); 

ObjectQuery qry = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, qry); 

ManagementObjectCollection return = search.Get(); 

foreach (ManagementObject rec in return) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Logged in user: " + rec["UserName"].ToString()); 
}
```

You may not need the `ConnectionOptions`...

Comment: Right, I believe it is the WMI_LogonSession - Do you have any helpful examples anywhere?

Comment: This code does work but it doesn't seem to work when you are not logged on to the computer.  I have 8 Servers that I am the admin of, and I want to get the list remotely of all the users that are logged on.  Do you think I need to use the Win32_LogonSession query, and if so do you know how to use it.  This is my first time working with WMI.

Comment: I'm not sure...  See if this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898757/vb-using-wmi-get-logged-in-users

Comment: If there are more than one connected users? because I need to run it on a windows 2008 server where a lot of terminal server users are connected at same time

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the qwinsta /server:server1 command from C# -- it was much easier

thanks Ken

All this checks all 8 servers at the same time -- I put the result in sql server

but you can do what ever you want

query_citrix.bat script
cd C:.......\bin\citrix_boxes
qwinsta -server:servername or ip > servername.txt

---

```
string sAppCitrixPath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\citrix_boxes\\";

//Run Script for current citrix boxes
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.FileName = sAppCitrixPath + "query_citrix.bat";
proc.StartInfo = si;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
proc.Close();

if (exitCode == 0)
{
      //Execute update who is on the Citrix_Boxes Currently
      DirectoryInfo dic = new DirectoryInfo(sAppCitrixPath);
      FileInfo[] fic = dic.GetFiles("*.txt");
      for (int i = 0; i < fic.Length; i++)
      {
         ParseQWinStaServerFile(fic[i].FullName.ToString(), fic[i].Name.ToString().ToUpper().Replace(".TXT",""));
        File.Delete(fic[i].FullName.ToString());
      }
}

   private void ParseQWinStaServerFile(string sLocation,string sServer)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(sLocation))
        {
            string sRecord = String.Empty;
            char[] cSep = new char[] {' '};

            bool bFirst = true;
            while ((sRecord = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (bFirst == false)
                {
                    string[] items = sRecord.Split(cSep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    //Make sure all columns are present on the split for valid records
                    if (sRecord.Substring(19, 1) != " ") // check position of user id to see if it's their 
                    {

                         //Send the user id and server name where you want to.
                         //here is your user 
                         id = items[1].ToString().ToLower().Trim()
                         //here is your server
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    bFirst = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```