# Stop a Windows Service on Log Off

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

We have a service in our project that runs and we need it to get a command on log off. We could send a command via our console, but the console is a separate program which could not be running. It does not necessarily need to stop, but it does need to get a command of some sort. Is there anything with in the service which can catch a Log Off event?

[10/17/12 10:45] - The service is running as Local System.

[10/17/12 12:07] - I added the following method, but I am not getting any output when I log off or onto the computer even though I am successfully writing to the log with this message I will try again rebuilding my solution, but wanted to post this here in case I am doing something wrong.

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
        WriteToDebugLog(new string[] { "OnSessionChange()",
                                        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " - Session change notice received: " + changeDescription.Reason.ToString() + "  Session ID: " + changeDescription.SessionId.ToString(),
                                       "Information" });
        base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to override [OnSessionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange(v=vs.100).aspx) .

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Services cannot run per-user, they're system wide. You may modify your service to detect when the user log-off but then it won't be started again when the user log-in again. As alternative you may use a second service to monitor log-in activity (using [OnSessionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as pointed out by @rene) and to start/stop the first service according.

It's a little bit tricky and you have to install a second service, I prefer a more simple solution using scripting.

### PowerShell

You can use two PowerShell scripts, this is to start the service:

```
Start-Service -name "YourServiceName"
```

This is to stop the service:

```
Stop-Service -name "YourServiceName"
```

To configure this scripts to be executed take a look [here](http://www.group-policy.com/ref/policy/2490/). In short you have to change policy configuration in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System!RunUserPSScriptsFirst` to run your scripts when needed.

### "Old" shell

You're not forced to use PowerShell, to start/stop a service can be done using shell commands:

```
sc start YourServiceName
```

and

```
sc stop YourServiceName
```

See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/345298/running-a-batch-file-on-logoff) for how to execute a batch file (or a command) at log-off. In short you have to add an entry to `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logoff` for log-off and `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logon` for log-on (but there are many many different places where you can put your scripts for log-on).

Comment: Would it be possible to run a batch command on Log on? (I am assuming it would be a very similar process, and perhaps a good way for us to finish our execution of the entire product).

Comment: Yes, for logon there are a lot of different places where you can put your scripts. The most similar one is HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logon (edited answer).

Comment: Okay, I may have to run a small program on logon/off to handle certain events which seems to be the way to handle it. Thanks for the information. I will see if this works before I accept this answer

Comment: Hey, will HKCU hit all users or only the user who installs the program?

Comment: HKCU is only for current user (the one who will install the program). You can install for another user using HKU and user's SID.

Comment: Okay, so what this says to me is that I have to have the Registry Entries as part of the installer, and visual studios _may_ have the installer recognize the difference and let this work how I need it to, the only difficult part will be to make sure that the registry points to the install directory (which I should be able to do with [TARGETDIR]). Hopefully this will work. Thanks so much for the help you have given me thus far :D

Comment: @BlazePhoenix yes! Of course the alternative is to have a second always running service that acts as "monitor" to control the main service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18187/discussion-between-blaze-phoenix-and-adriano)

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a group policy help? If you're on Windows 7, click start, write "group policy" and click the "Edit group policy" choice. from there, go to User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts  (Logon / Logoff)

In here you can add a script that starts or stops your service

Answer (score 0):

You can let your service work all the time and check if specific user is logged in, look on this SO answer how to check logged in users

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065660/351383