# Keep jenkins slave offline when user logs into Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to configure Jenkins to mark Windows slave offline when a user starts using slave?

**EDIT:** By starts using I mean user logs on.

Comment: I think you need to define "starts using slave": does it mean user logged in? moved a mouse? CPU usage increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [Slave Prerequisites Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slave+Prerequisites+Plugin%20Slave%20Prerequisites%20Plugin). 
It allows to add job prerequisites in terms of a script:

> Set a script to be run on slave node before the job can run on them.
>   If returning a non 0 status, the node will be vetoed for job
>   execution, and either another node will be choosen, either the job
>   will get back to build queue waiting for an available node to match
>   its prerequisites.

with the following windows batch script:

```
python.exe -c "import psutil; assert len(psutil.get_users())==0"
```

you'll have to get [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/%20psutil), but you may be able to craft something with pure Windows shell. The most obvious disadvantage is that we are going through many systems, instead of just using the ones that are marked as available.

Comment: A more Jenkins-native solution than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since a [Jenkins slave can be registered as a Windows service](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service), one way would be to ensure that there is no currently logged on user.

One could conceive a Windows tasks, running regularely, which would check if a user is logged on, and:

- if there is one, would *stop* the service.
- if not, (re)start the same Jenkins slave agent windows service.

For checking who is logged on, see "[From WindowsService how can I find currently logged in user from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065561/from-windowsservice-how-can-i-find-currently-logged-in-user-from-c)" for one way.

Comment: This requires a separate polling task running, that will always be a little late with data. May as well start each task by asserting if there is a user logged on. I was thinking more in terms of plugin that adds a monitor on a node, like https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Nodemonitoring

Comment: @Oleksiy then have your Node monitor execute http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/701515b3-9af3-49f4-b624-09a083cbed6b or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545