# How can Windows service running as System account get current user's \AppData\Local\ special-folder?

Tags: c#, windows-services, special-folders, local-system-account

My app is a windows desktop exe, and windows service which runs under the System account. My windows service needs to integrate with a 3rd party app that the user will also install which stores some config info in an ini file within one of the [windows special-folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) at: C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\[3rd party app name]

How can my Windows Service retrieve the current user's path to that folder to read the ini file in it, when the windows service runs as System account?

Ideally, I would have used something like

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

which returns the correct **\AppData\Local\** folder when run from an app running as the current user.

But because my windows service is running as SYSTEM (which cannot be changed) that method instead returns:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local

So how can my windows service get the currently logged in user's LocalApplicationData special folder?

Comment: step 1: identify the user whose folder you're looking for. step 2: ???, step 3: profit. Before you begin anything, the first question you need to answer is "how will I know what folder to look in?". Do you always know what [UserName] is or might that change? If it's static, that simplifies things, if it changes...well you've got to sort that out before you figure out how to access their app data folder.

Comment: It should be apparent that a user's folder (including subfolders) is an inappropriate storage location in this case. Store your data in a location that is common to all users such as `%ProgramData%`.

Comment: @gilliduck I do not know the [UserName], my app and windows service may be installed on 100s of machines.

Comment: @user09938 It is a 3rd party app that is putting its config info into that C:\\\[UserName]\\AppData\\Local folder, so I have no control over that and cannot change its storage location. But my service needs to read the config info in there.

Comment: It's unclear what your program does such that it needs to run as _SYSTEM (which cannot be changed)_. Since more than one user could be logged in at a time, it seems that you are really only left with the option of checking all users' folders for the data and determine which has the desired data (ie: the file with the most recent lastupdated time).

Comment: The current user _is_ System.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Well, yes? But that System account still needs to retrieve the path to the normal user's C:\\[UserName]\\AppData\\Local folder, when I do not know in advance what [UserName] is. So, I am not sure how that helps?

Comment: My point is that from the perspective of the service running in the System account there is no such thing as `the normal user` - there could be any number of users logged into the box while the service is running - or none at all.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError OK, then it is the currently logged in user that I am considering here. I am confident that in my case 99% of the time there will only be 1 logged in user.

Comment: Okay, answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065561/from-windowsservice-how-can-i-find-currently-logged-in-user-from-c) may have some clues for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to get a list of logged in users. Once you have a list of logged in users, then you can check the last updated time of the file ([File.GetLastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0#System_IO_File_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_)) that you're interested in.

**Add Reference**: System.Management

**Create a class** (name: UserInfo.cs)

**UserInfo.cs**:

```
public class UserInfo : IComparable<UserInfo>
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string DesktopName { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocalAccount { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsRoamingConfigured { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime LastUploadTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUseTime { get; set; }
    public string LocalPath { get; set; }
    public bool IsProfileLoaded { get; set; } = false;
    public string ProfilePath { get; set; }
    public string SID { get; set; }
    public uint SIDType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(UserInfo other)
    {
        //sort by name
        if (this.Caption == other.Caption)
            return 0;
        else if (String.Compare(this.Caption, other.Caption) > 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        output += $"Caption: '{Caption}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"Domain: '{Domain}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"Username: '{Username}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"IsProfileLoaded: '{IsProfileLoaded}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"IsRoamingConfigured: '{IsRoamingConfigured}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"LocalPath: '{LocalPath}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"LastUseTime: '{LastUseTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")}'{Environment.NewLine}";
        output += $"SID: '{SID}'{Environment.NewLine}";

        return output;
    }
}
```

**GetLoggedInUserInfo**:

```
public List<UserInfo> GetLoggedInUserInfo()
{
    List<UserInfo> users = new List<UserInfo>();

    //create reference
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcherUserAccount = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption, Domain, LocalAccount, Name, SID, SIDType, Status FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled = false"))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject objUserAccount in searcherUserAccount.Get())
        {
            if (objUserAccount == null)
                continue;

            //create new instance
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();

            string caption = objUserAccount["Caption"].ToString();

            //set value
            userInfo.Caption = caption;
            userInfo.Domain = objUserAccount["Domain"].ToString();

            userInfo.IsLocalAccount = (bool)objUserAccount["LocalAccount"];
            userInfo.Username = objUserAccount["Name"].ToString();

            string sid = objUserAccount["SID"].ToString();

            userInfo.SID = sid;
            userInfo.SIDType =  Convert.ToUInt32(objUserAccount["SIDType"]);
            userInfo.Status = objUserAccount["Status"].ToString();

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcherUserProfile = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT LastUseTime, LastUploadTime, Loaded, LocalPath, RoamingConfigured FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE SID = '{sid}'"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject objUserProfile in searcherUserProfile.Get())
                {
                    if (objUserProfile == null)
                        continue;

                    if (objUserProfile["LastUploadTime"] != null)
                    {
                        string lastUploadTimeStr = objUserProfile["LastUploadTime"].ToString();

                        if (lastUploadTimeStr.Contains("."))
                            lastUploadTimeStr = lastUploadTimeStr.Substring(0, lastUploadTimeStr.IndexOf("."));

                        DateTime lastUploadTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                        //convert DateTime
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lastUploadTimeStr, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", cultureInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out lastUploadTime))
                            userInfo.LastUseTime = lastUploadTime;

                        //set value
                        userInfo.LastUploadTime = lastUploadTime;
                    }


                    string lastUseTimeStr = objUserProfile["LastUseTime"].ToString();

                    if (lastUseTimeStr.Contains("."))
                        lastUseTimeStr = lastUseTimeStr.Substring(0, lastUseTimeStr.IndexOf("."));

                    DateTime lastUseTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                    //convert DateTime
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lastUseTimeStr, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", cultureInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out lastUseTime))
                        userInfo.LastUseTime = lastUseTime;

                    //Debug.WriteLine($"LastUseTime: '{objUserProfile["LastUseTime"].ToString()}' After Conversion: '{lastUseTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")}'");

                    userInfo.LocalPath = objUserProfile["LocalPath"].ToString();
                    userInfo.IsProfileLoaded = (bool)objUserProfile["Loaded"];
                    userInfo.IsRoamingConfigured = (bool)objUserProfile["RoamingConfigured"];
                }
            }

            if (userInfo.IsProfileLoaded)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(userInfo.ToString());

                //add
                users.Add(userInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    //sort by LastUseTime
    users.Sort(delegate (UserInfo info1, UserInfo info2) { return info1.LastUseTime.CompareTo(info2.LastUseTime); });

    return users;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
List<UserInfo> users = GetLoggedInUserInfo();
```

**Resources**:

- [Win32_UserAccount Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount)
- [Win32_UserProfile Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409(v=vs.85))
- [ManagementObjectSearcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)
- [ManagementObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)
- [File.GetLastWriteTime Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0#System_IO_File_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_)

Comment: It's WMI method right? Should we run it after user logged in? Could you share how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Currently I know getting SESSION Changed message. It there more simple way?